# How to store more than one decision tree in an object in R

Tags: r

I want to create a forest of decision trees. And for this I want to store 'n' decision trees in an 
   object. So is there a way in R in which I can store all different decision trees?

Answer (score 1):

Just put the trees in a list.

```
library(rpart)
Forest = list()
for(i in 1:5) {
    RS = sample(150,100)
    RPI = rpart(Species ~ ., data=iris[RS,])
    Forest[[i]] = RPI
}
```